# Database structure for avoiding data loss, deadlock & worst performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, database-design

Below Image is my database struture image.
[image]
I have 100+ sensors which are sending constant data to respective machines.
I have 5-7 different machines which is having different SQL express database installed in it.
All the machines will send its respective data to one SERVER.
Every second each mahcine  will send 10 rows as a bulk data to server stored procedure

PROBLEM : managing large data coming from every machines to single server to avoiding deadlock / delay in performance.

**Background Logic**
Bulk data from machines are stored into temporary table 
& than using that temp table i am looping through each record for processing.
Finally in sp_processed_filtered_data  lots of insert & updates are present. & there are nested sp's for processing that filtered data.

Current Logic :

Step : 1

```
Every Machine will send data to SP_Manage stored procedure which consist of bulk data in XML format, which we are converting in SQL table format.
This data is row data. so we filter this data.

Let's say after filtering 3 rows are remained.

so I want to process that each row now.
```

Step : 2

```
As I have to process each rows I have to loop through each row to send data to SP_Process_Filetered_Data.


Now this SP is containing complex logic. 
I am looping though each records & every machines will send data parallelly.
```

So I am afraid will it be causing data loss or dead lock.

Comment: When it sends it to the same server finally, what action is actually happening, inserts? updates? The operation types and isolation levels at play here have a direct impact. At present you are asking us about potential problems, and not a real one.

Comment: Bulk data from machines are stored in to temporary tables & than using that temp table i am looping through each record & finally in sp_processed_filtered_data  lots of insert & updates are present.

Comment: The details about the specifics of where the multiple procs actually touch the same tables / rows are needed in the question - to ask about a deadlock scenario you have to provide those details. The more specific / detailed you can be, the better. Please edit in as much detail as you can expose.

Comment: Whether looping though data for such a fast transaction is a good option or I can do any other process for processing that bulk data

Comment: Moved to chat (https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164688/room-for-andrew-and-hardik-parmar) to avoid lengthy comments

Comment: Deadlocks are actually very easy to avoid: **always** lock objects in the same order, and **never** escalate a lock (for example, trying to get a write lock on an object you already hold a read lock on is escalating a lock.  Never do that - release the read lock, then get the write lock - and don't break your lock order while doing that).  Those are the necessary and sufficient conditions to never deadlock.  If you do that, you will **never** have any deadlocks.  If you don't do that, you can have deadlocks.